# Is there a specific term for an oblique cone whose vertex does not lie above its base?

Tags: geometry, terminology

Consider the following cone:

[image: the cone in question]

Assume a circular base (but I don't think that's really critical to my question). Note that the line connecting the vertex of the cone to the plane of the base, where the line is at a right angle to the plane, falls *outside* the cone itself. Or put another way, if one extrudes the base as a cylinder at right angles to the base's plane, the vertex of the cone lies outside this cylinder.

> Does this particular kind of cone have an official name?

I have spent a fair amount of time searching the web, to no avail. I'm not sure if there simply is no official name, or if I just don't know what search terms to use to yield a result.

- I'm aware that cones can be "right" or "oblique", where these terms describe whether the line connecting the vertex of the cone with the center of the base forms a right angle with the plane of the base or not.
- I'm also aware that the terms "right", "acute", and "obtuse" are used to describe the angle formed at the vertex of the cone (i.e. in some sense, the angle of the cone's "opening").

But I have no idea what I should call the above cone, so as to distinguish it from cones where the slant is not such that the vertex is outside the base of the cone.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's just called "oblique."

Answer (score 2):

It is called an oblique cone. Its vertex isn't on the top of the base, making it  slanted.

Comment: As I noted in my question, I do understand that cone _is a type of_ "oblique cone". E.g. [_"one where the vertex is not over the center of its circular base"_](http://www.mathopenref.com/coneoblique.html). But so is a cone where the vertex is positioned within the bounds of the base. I'm looking for a more specific term.